# MVC: Cannot get autocomplete to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking at the book MVC 2 in Action. The chapter on autocomplete is at the end which I use as reference.
In the controller, the Json results that is returned is not transformed into a list for autocomplete. The book did not use Json but I could not use their alternative with a generic list.

So my View is;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.WebUI.Models.HolidayRequestViewModel>" %>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input#SearchText").autocomplete('<%: Url.Action("FindNames", "Employee") %>');
    });

</script>
<p>You must make sure that the correct person to approve your Annual Leave is currently selected</p>
<p>Your current approver is <%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ApproverName) %></p>
<p>If you want to change your approver, enter his/her name here and make your selection.</p>
<p><%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchText) %></p>
<div id="test-panel" class="ui-state-default"> This panel will disappear on command.</div>
```

And my controller is;

```
    public JsonResult FindNames(string q)
    {
        List<EmployeeName> filteredEmployees =
            Employee.GetAllCurrentEmployeesNames().Where(x => x.Fullname.ToLower().Contains(q.ToLower())).ToList();
        return Json(filteredEmployees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

*** EDITED ***
The problem with sending the parameter has now been fixed by using "string q". Obvious eh? Now it is a case of getting the JSON returned into an autocomplete list.

Comment: I don't know the ASP.NET autocomplete mechanism but I expect the problem is the name of the parameter on the URL. What exact URL is the autocomplete generating - what's it naming the parameter? Do you have any specific routes set up for this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a helper for this, you can use it without having to know jQuery at all

look how it works: **http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/AutocompleteDemo**

you can download the library from here: http://awesome.codeplex.com/

Comment: This looks fantastic. Well worth knowing about

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [jquery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) the query string parameter is called `term` by default. So:

```
public ActionResult FindNames(string term)
```

Of course this could be personalized:

```
$('input#SearchText').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<%: Url.Action("FindNames", "Employee") %>',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { searchText: request.term },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The question is whether it is worth it.

Comment: You are on the right lines. Actually I should have copied my book, which specified FindNames(string q), so q rather than term. Why on earth that should be, I have no idea.

Comment: @arame3333, if I remember correctly `q` was used by the older jquery autocomplete plugin which is now deprecated in favor of jquery UI and which is what I would recommend you using.

Comment: Actually working from the book, I am using this pluggin; https://github.com/dyve/jquery.autocomplete/blob/master/index.html which is now more than a year old.

Comment: @arame3333, this is the old autocomplete. It is deprecated in favor of [jquery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which was the one I linked in my answer.

Comment: I was getting there with your solution. My problem was converting the data from the controller method into a format that will display on my form. Your solution would have worked once I got that right, but I think you should look at the helpers in the other answer.